# Detect quoted_printable while extracting links from imap emails

Tags: php, imap

I have the following:

```
if($emails) {
    $output = '';
    rsort($emails);
    foreach($emails as $email_number) {
        foreach ([1,2] as $option) {
            $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $email_number);
            $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
            $message = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,$option));

            $regex = '#\bhttps?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#';
            preg_match_all($regex, $message, $links);
            foreach ($links[0] AS $link) {
                $output .= $link.'<br>';
            }
    }}
    echo $output;
}
```

This works okay except some links contain � and some contain a small empty quare box.

If I don't use `quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,$option))`

Then some links contain =3D.

I can' seem to figure out how to get this right.

I have also tried:

```
$structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $email_number, FT_UID);
if($structure->encoding == "4"){
    $message = base64_decode(imap_fetchbody($inbox, imap_msgno($inbox, $email_number), $option));
} elseif ($structure->encoding == "3") { 
    $message = imap_qprint(map_fetchbody($inbox, imap_msgno($inbox, $email_number), $option));
} else { 
    $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,$option);
}
```

I simply cannot figure out how to do this.